# Android Studio - Not recognizing syntax errors

Tags: java, android, android-studio, ide

I've tried to Invalidate Caches/Restart and Clean Project several times.

> I'm running the following version of Android studio.

```
Android Studio 3.2.1
Build #AI-181.5540.7.32.5056338, built on October 8, 2018
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1136-b06 x86_64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
macOS 10.13.6
```

**The issue is the code is not being autocorrected by the IDE and none of the code assist features are working.**

I left some intentional errors in my code and the compiler did not output any errors.

**I'm also getting this error whenever I open a project:**

```
Error while indexing /Users/christopherholmes/AndroidStudioProjects/QuizTwo/app/build/generated/not_namespaced_r_class_sources/debug/processDebugResources/r/com/example/christopherholmes/quiztwo/R.java
```

Not sure what to make of this.

*EDIT*
So I closed and re-opened Android Studio like 3 times and now things are back to normal. Crossing fingers... I will update if I run into any more issues.

*EDIT*

The problem has returned. To attempt to solve the problem I have

1) Upgraded Android Studio
2) Invalidated and Cleaned Cache
3) Rebuilt the project

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check your directory of adb. It is important to fill correct directory for studio otherwise it will create problem.
The directory will look like../Users//Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools..This is default directory.Make sure your adb is located in that directory.

Comment: my adb is located in that directory